# iOS safari is auto expanding iframe

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

I can't control the size of iframes in iOS. The content inside seems to expand the whole iframe. I have used both css and javascript to control the size without any success.

I have tried with both of these:

```
iframe {
  height:100px !important;
  width:100px !important;
}

$('iframe).css({'height':'100px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

To make embedded content responsive, you need to add a containing wrapper around the iframe. Your markup would be as follows:

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4aQwT3n2c1Q" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not my problem, the problem is i can't control the size of iframe on iOS.